# MySQL database query and update

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I was wondering if somebody knew a better way to do the following:

I need to query a database and return a value (in this case an int), then using this value, calculate the new value and update the database with this new value.

My current approach is using a method to get the current int value from the database, passing this value to another method to perform the calculations and then passing the new value to a third method to update the database.

So, the problem(?) with this is that it opens a new connection from the pool when getting the initial value from the db and then when updating it. Obviously it closes the connection at the end of the method but is there some easier / better way of doing this ? It seems a bit messy.

Comment: i think you missed one tag. You are using Java on the server side?

Comment: yea, im using java server side. Added it now thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT fieldValue FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;
 UPDATE table_name SET fieldToUpdate = fieldValue + 1;
```

See the [`UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: He uses a pool. And if I understand correctly the question he isn't using the same connection to select the value and update, so for update will work only if he changes the logic to use one connection, right?

Comment: it's a option too. Just trying to make sure that Predz will understand your answer.

Comment: @SérgioMichels, I agree with you, but the OP mentioned that he uses three different methods, and as I understood that is becouse he didn't know a better aproach.

Comment: im retarded and cant figure out the tags for code. will post again in a few minutes when i learn

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to open a new connection for each query.  Just open a connection at the start of your request, save its reference to a global variable that you can use in all your methods, and close it at the end of your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the calculations in SQL:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate
SET ColumnB = 
    Calculations( ( SELECT ColumnA
                    FROM TableToSelect
                    WHERE (conditions for selecting)
                  )
                )
WHERE (conditions for updating)
```

Comment: @Predz This would require you to create his own function, Calculations(), http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function-udf.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you could exploit multiple-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate U JOIN TableToSelect S ON ( -- join condition for selection value to process )
SET U.ColumnB = Calculations( S.ColumnC )
WHERE U.ColumnC = -- whatever selection condition
```